# Get angle of unknown end point of a line

Tags: c++, math, vector

**Short Version:**

Basically, I'm trying to figure out the X and Y values of an unknown `Point C` using the ending point of `Line AB` ( `Point B` ).

I tried using `atan2( B.y, B.x)` but it gives me the angle respective to the `X-Axis` which leads to wrong coordinates. I figured that I needed to get the angle formed by `Line BC` and the imaginary horizontal axis in which `Point B` lies ( `Angle P` ). Is there a way to obtain that angle? If getting that angle would not do what I want to do, what would?

**Long Version:**

I'm trying to do some math using C++ and I got stuck with this certain problem.

I have two vectors, `Vector A` and `Vector B` ( illustrated by `Point A` and `Point B` and they form the `line AB` ). Now, I want to get `Vector C` ( `Point C` ), which is `L` units away from `Vector B` ( illustrated by `Line BC` ).

[image: Case 1: Get point if B.y > A.y]

I searched around, read some books, and got this formula to get the point that I need.

```
/* Let:
 * L = length from B to C
 * ( B.x, B.y ) = start point
 * ( C.x, C.y ) = end point 
 * theta = angle respective to X-Axis ( using atan2( B.y, B.x ) )
 */

// To get C.x use formula cos( theta ) = ( C.x - B.x ) / L then derive
C.x = ( L * cos( theta ) ) + B.x;

// To get C.y use formula sin( theta ) = ( C.y - B.y ) / L then derive
C.y = ( L * sin( theta ) ) + B.y;
```

However, this does not result into `Point C` as illustrated above because the resulting `C` will be respective to the `X-Axis`. After reading some more, I figured out that I need to get the angle ( illustrated by purple `Angle P` ) between the `Line BC` ( pale red line ) and the imaginary horizontal axis ( teal line ) in which `Point B` lies.

Another example:

[image: Case 2: Get point if B.y < A.y]

In this case, using the formula above would result to `C` being in the wrong place ( above `( X , 5 )` )

I am not sure if getting `Angle P` would do what I want, if you know a much more appropriate answer, please do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do to is to create a tempB as if A was the origin(so you can find angle of B to A and so forth).

Subtract A's values from B.

```
tempB.x = B.x - A.x
tempB.y = B.y - A.y
```

Then you can use atan2 along with sin/cos (your formulas) to obtain C.x and C.y.

```
theta = atan2(tempB.y, tempB.x)
C.x = ( L * cos( theta ) ) + B.x;
C.y = ( L * sin( theta ) ) + B.y;
```

Another alternative is to obtain the unit vector of tempB.

```
magnitude = sqrt( pow(tempB.x,2) + pow(tempB.y,2))
unit.x = tempB.x/magnitude
unit.y = tempB.y/magnitude
```

Multiplying this unit vector by L gives you the offset from B.

```
C.x = B.x + unit.x * L
C.y = B.y + unit.y * L
```

Comment: So, instead of using `B.x` and `B.y` in the sin/cos formula, I would use `tempB.x` and `tempB.y` instead?

Comment: @LanceGray Only in the `atan2` call. `tempB` is only for determining the angle. the offset(`C.x = ( L * cos( theta ) ) + B.x;`) would still use `B.x`

Comment: Implemented it and it works. But kinda hard to grasp since it uses Trigonometry ( which I am honestly not that good at ). Thanks.

Comment: @LanceGray Well surely the point is that you don't need to use trigonometry. Ethan's second solution (like my solution) does not use trigonometry. Useful since you say you aren't very good at it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need trig for this. It's simple proportions. I handy rule I found is that if you find yourself using sin, cos *and* atan2 then you're probably doing it wrong.

Here's how to do it without trig

```
dx = B.x - A.x;
dy = B.y - A.y;
dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
C.x = B.x + L*(dx/dist);
C.y = B.y + L*(dy/dist);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you explain how it happens? A link to the explanation will do. I feel I'm going to be using vectors a lot in the future.

Comment: @LanceGray It's just basic straight line geometry isn't it? I'm afraid I don't have a link to any explanation but basically you are extending the line AB by an amount proportional to L/(length of AB).

Answer (score 1):

What you need (in vector terms) is `C = B + L*normalize(B-A)`. If you will be doing a lot more of this sort of calculation it would be worth using a vector library so that you can write your code exactly like that. Otherwise, You should use John's answer, which breaks down the same calculation into its elementary steps.

Edit: Here's a library you could use quite easily (it's just header files): [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/)

Comment: I was a reading a book about animating using code but it was in AS 3.0 and it included writing a custom Vector class with `clone()`, `truncate()`, `normalize()`, and other methods. I wasn't able to rewrite it in C++ so I resorted to Trigonometry.

Comment: If you are interested in writing animation code, getting familiar with using vectors is worth the time spent. I've edited my answer with a link to a library you could use, instead of re-writing normalize() etc. yourself.